# What configuration required to run maven project with selenium (TestNG) from command line?

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, testng

Required Configuration for running maven project from command line.

Comment: Did you check - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10391312/testng-surefire-run-suite-with-maven-command-line

Comment: @Helping Hands - I had tried it but it didn't work for me.

Comment: ok..does that answer helped you here which is posted by Sagar007

Comment: @ Helping Hands - Yes it was helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very Nice question.
I had also stuck with same question but I have found solution.
Required two maven plug-ins which are given under.
Please make sure your JDK 1.7 and JRE 7 version is configure in your project. 
Add this plugin to your pom.xml and follow this step:

1 mvn clean

2 mvn install

3 mvn exec:java

Step 3 is required to run project without specify main class

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
                 <configuration>
                         <source>1.7</source>
                         <target>1.7</target>
                         <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                         <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                         <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                         <executable>${env.JAVA_HOME}/bin/javac</executable>
                         <fork>true</fork>
                 </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>  
                   <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>  
                   <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>  
                   <version>1.2.1</version>  
                   <configuration>  
                      <mainClass>com.mainClass</mainClass>  
                   </configuration>  
             </plugin>
```

Comment: You should share how you got solution so questioner can solve his/her issue also.

Comment: I had share my answer. By mistake I had click on Enter Key.

Comment: @Sagar007 Very detailed description. It solved my problem also. Thanks :)